# Accessing "this" from event in prototype

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, hammer.js

Consider the following code... using Hammer.js but I think it might be a generic Javascript question:

```
var drawLayer = new DrawLayer(document.getElementById('canvasContainer'));

function DrawLayer(targetElement) {
    this.foo = "bar";

    this.gestureDetection = new Hammer.Manager(targetElement);
    this.gestureDetection.add(new Hammer.Pan({
            direction : Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL,
            threshold : 0
        }));
    this.gestureDetection.add(new Hammer.Press({
            time : 0,
            threshold : 5
        }));
    this.gestureDetection.on("press", this.drawBegin);
    this.gestureDetection.on("panmove", this.drawMove);
    this.gestureDetection.on("panend pressup", this.drawEnd);

    this.drawBegin("INIT TEST");
}

DrawLayer.prototype.drawBegin = function (gestureData) {
    console.log(typeof(this.foo));
    console.log("DRAW BEGIN!");
}

DrawLayer.prototype.drawMove = function (gestureData) {
    console.log(this.foo);
    console.log("DRAW MOVE!");
}

DrawLayer.prototype.drawEnd = function (gestureData) {
    console.log(this.foo);
    console.log("DRAW END!");
}
```

When I run it at first, I get this, as expected:

```
string
DRAW BEGIN!
```

But then when actually processing the gestures (i.e. when the drawing stuff is called via events), I get:

```
undefined
DRAW BEGIN!
```

More to this point- it seems that when processing any of those drawBegin/etc. methods, "this" is undefined, as though it lost scope somehow?

I would love both a solution and an explanation. Thanks!

Comment: The value of `this` is determined **only** by how a function is invoked. Instead of passing `obj.drawMove` directly to event handler registration functions, pass an anonymous wrapper function that calls `drawMove` via the object reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind "this" to an event callback like so:

```
this.gestureDetection.on("press", this.drawBegin.bind(this));
```

When the callback is triggered by the event, it should have the correct "this".

Answer (score 2):

The value of "this" depends on the way the function has been invoked.

In the first case, you are calling the drawBegin function directly from your DrawLayer class:

```
this.drawBegin("INIT TEST");
```

in that case, this variable represents the DrawLayer obj.

When you call a function through an event

```
this.gestureDetection.on("press", this.drawBegin);
```

"this" variable may be wrapped by the function "on" to represent anything else (usually the event itself or the object who triggered the event).

Try to change your code to the following and see if it works:

```
function DrawLayer(targetElement) {
    this.foo = "bar";

    this.gestureDetection = new Hammer.Manager(targetElement);
    this.gestureDetection.add(new Hammer.Pan({
            direction : Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL,
            threshold : 0
    }));
    this.gestureDetection.add(new Hammer.Press({
            time : 0,
            threshold : 5
    }));
    this.gestureDetection.on("press", this.drawBeginWrapper);
    this.gestureDetection.on("panmove", this.drawMove);
    this.gestureDetection.on("panend pressup", this.drawEnd);

    var _self = this;

    this.drawBeginWrapper = function(gestureData) {
          _self.drawBegin(gestureData);
    } 

    this.drawBegin("INIT TEST");
}
```